# Point to drag on the surface of a sphere THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create a globe with points that users can drag with their mouse cursor.

[My Code](https://moon1ock.github.io/)

I have set up the main sphere, and a small red sphere as one example point, but how do I make sure that the small point only moves over the surface of the main sphere?

PS: in the code, I have basically created Two spheres: the main one, and a smaller one colored in red. I have added orbit controls, and a Raycaster to drag the small sphere, but I am having trouble with limiting the smaller sphere to the surface of the bigger one

Comment: You need to add the code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Links to external resources tend to break and the resource may no longer be available in the future.

Comment: @Rabbid76 stack overflow does not let me add even a small chunk of code, since `THREE.js` is rather wordy. I did add extra elaboration however

Comment: Adding an entire project is undesirable. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=raycaster#api/en/core/Raycaster). The method would go like this:

1. On `mousedown`, configure the raycaster to cast from your mouse position.
2. Check for an intersection against your **dot/dots**.
3. If you intersected a dot, put your application into a "dragging" state.
4. On `mousemove` events, update the raycaster with the latest mouse position, and cast against the **globe**.
5. Set the dot's position to be the intersection point of the ray on the globe.
6. On `mouseup`, unset your "dragging" state.

This could get weird toward the horizons of the globe because the ray will start to become tangent to the globe's curve, potentially causing the movement to become twitchy/over-sensitive. But that's something you'd have to deal with.

Raycasting every time the mouse moves can be process expensive. You may find you only need to update the dot every N (small number) `mousemove` events to maintain a smooth interaction rate.

These methods can also be expensive for memory. Make sure you reuse your `Raycaster` and any temporary vector objects so you don't have a runaway memory heap.